# JS Json parsing faster alternative

Tags: javascript, json, http, xmlhttprequest, esp32

I have an esp32 chip (32-bit microcontroller with WiFi communication) that records important data into local memory. I need to send these data to the user webbrowser for drawing a chart. It is about 1MB per hour and I need charts with up to 5days of data (up to 120MB of raw data).

At the moment I have written an http server and JSON parser. When user requests data, raw data from memory are read and parsed into JSON for sanding. Parsing raw data into text json result in extending each 1MB (of raw) into about 2MB (of text).

Local browser waits for JSON file and using JS JSON.parse(this.responseText) parses it into object for adding into an array.

JSON.parse tooks lots of time! About 5 sec for each 2MB (1MB of raw).

```
function loadChartData(address) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = loadChartDataReady;
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://192.168.1.1/"+address, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
function loadChartDataReady() {
    if (this.readyState != 4) return;
    if (this.status != 200) { return; }
    try {
        var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        for(var i = 1; i < json.length; i++) {
            var obj = json[i];
            series.splice(i - 1, 0, {ts: obj[0], time: obj[1], s: obj[2], m: obj[3], on: obj[4]} );
        }
        updateChart();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("error: " + err);
    }
}
```

I am wandering what can I do for speeding up my code 
both in terms of used memory and execution time.

- Can I parse raw data somehow in javascript?
- Can I change JSON.parse into some another function for speeding up?
- Can I change XMLHttpRequest into something another for start parsing data while they are still being sent?

Comment: Maybe you need to make multiple requests instead of just one.

Comment: I have my request splited into block of these 1MB (raw).
Browser requests these 1MB, than parse, than requests next block